# Shell script (assign to variable) not working

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "$1" ] #parameter is file name, if i exists...
then
    VARIABLE=`cat "$1"` #assign what's inside into VARIABLE
fi
```

I've tried `bash -x script_01.sh "file"` and the tracing works:

```
+ '[' -f file ']'
++ cat file
+ VARIABLE='Wednesday, November  4, 2015 04:45:47 PM CET'
```

But the problem is that when I echo $VARIABLE, it's empty. Do you guys have any tips on how to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: It works for me. I added `echo $VARIABLE` to the end of your script and saved it under script.sh. If I run `bash script.sh script.sh`, it echoes the contents of the script as expected.

Comment: Yeah, when I add echo at the end of the script, it works. But outside of the script it doesn't. I guess it's in the other process that I'm running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VARIABLE` is set in the process that runs the script, not the process which *called* the script. If you want to set it in your current environment, you need to source the file instead.

```
. script_01.sh "file"
```

Comment: So if I understood correctly, there are two bashes, bash1: the one I'm using right now and bash2: the one that runs the script. So VARIABLE will be set to `cat file` only in bash2 while in bash1 it won't be anything yet?

I don't understand the second path. I did use "file" as parameter, right?

Comment: Right; variables are "local" to the script/shell in which they run. So although `VARIABLE` is correctly set within the run of `script_01.sh`, it goes away once that script exits.

Comment: So in order to get it out of the scripting I would have to add "export VARIABLE"?

Comment: No, `export` is a one-way process, for passing information from the parent to its child. There is no way (by design) for a child to affect the environment of its parent, which is why you have to source the file as I've shown so that the code executes in the same process.